# How to get and work with a RGB Value in Python?

Tags: python, colors, rgb, detection, pyautogui

I want to create a script that detects the color of a pixel, and if it's red (for example) it should further move on in the script. So I make a screenshot of a certain region, save it and detect the color of the pixel I want to.

```
current = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(116, 710, 40, 15))
current.save("./current.png")

def rgb_of_pixel(img_path, x, y):
    im = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
    r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
    a = (r, g, b)
    return a

img = "./current.png"
print(rgb_of_pixel(img, 5, 5))
time.sleep(1) code here
```

That's what I got so far. I can print it out, but I am not sure how to make an if statement with it. Again, I want it to do something if the color of the pixel is red.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do that (if I understood your query correctly):

```
if a == (255, 0, 0):
    print('It is red!')
```

Comment: The console shows me this error: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: You need to indent the content of your function.

Comment: Now I get another error: NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: You need to say ' a = rgb_of_pixel(img, 5, 5) '

Comment: Thank you! Got It

Answer (score 0):

This mostly depends on what you call red, I think, not really a programming issue, you could, for instance, call something red if the red channel is more than 100, and is more than twice as large as either green or blue, the code for that would be:

```
def isRed(a):
    r,g,b = a
    if r>100 and g<r/2 and b<r/2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```